# Limits and continuity to prove finite times 0 is 0

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $ E \subset R$ , p is a limit point of $E$, and $f,g$ are real valued functions on $E$ , if $g$ is bounded on $E$  and      $\lim_{x \to p}f(x)g(x) = 0  $.

To prove this

since $g$ is bounded on $E$ , there exist a bounded value $M$ 
$$g < M$$
and since $ \lim{x \to p} = 0  $ then $\\$
 $ \lim_{x \to p}f(x)\times  \lim_{x \to p} g(x) =  0 \times M(finite  \   number) = 0    $

I'm not sure just showing $g(x)$ is finite and 0 * finite number is 0 is enough to show this question .

Comment: To prove *what*? Where is your statement? You have supposed some things, and then started a statement ("if..."), but you never finished. What is it that you are trying to show? Also, $$\lim_{x\to p}=0$$ is nonsense. Are you assuming that $$\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=0,$$ and trying to show that $$\lim_{x\to p}f(x)g(x)=0,$$ rather than assuming the latter?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you mean the following:

> Suppose that $E\subseteq\Bbb R,$ $p$ is a limit point of $E,$ and $f,g$ are real-valued functions on $E$. If $g$ is bounded on $E$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to p}f(x)=0,$ then $\lim\limits_{x\to p}f(x)g(x)=0.$

To prove this, we can use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of function limits. In particular, we are trying to show that for all $\epsilon>0,$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)g(x)-0|<\epsilon$ whenever $x\in E$ such that $0<|x-p|<\delta.$ As a hint for how to do this, observe that $$|f(x)g(x)-0|=|f(x)g(x)|=|f(x)|\cdot|g(x)|=|f(x)-0|\cdot|g(x)|.$$ What can we say about $|g(x)|$ for all $x\in E$? What can we say about $|f(x)-0|$ for any $c>0$ and for $x\in E$ sufficiently close to $p$? How does this help us?

Alternately, if you already know that, *under certain conditions*, we have $$\lim_{x\to p}\bigl[f(x)g(x)\bigr]=\left[\lim_{x\to p}f(x)\right]\left[\lim_{x\to p}g(x)\right],$$ then all you have to do is prove that those conditions are satisfied, and you're done.